# Persistence provider not found exception in GWT app

Tags: java, gwt, persistence

Hey I'm getting a persistence provide not found exception the code for my persistence.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="GWTSales"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.Branch</class>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.Customer</class>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.Employee</class>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.Product</class>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.Purchase</class>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.PurchaseDetail</class>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.PurchaseDetailPK</class>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.Sale</class>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.SalesDesk</class>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.SalesDetail</class>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.SalesDetailPK</class>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.Stock</class>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.Supplier</class>
    <class>com.jeroennouws.sales.beans.User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sales" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and the code that generates this exception is

```
 public BranchJpaController() {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("GWTSales");
}
```

I have tried all different kinds of things by now, eclipselink jar file is in my WEB-INF/lib folder and my persistence.xml file is in my src/META-INF folder.
Does this has something to do with the GWT Jetty server in the eclipse plugin or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the MySQL JDBC Driver is in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

I hope it helps.

Comment: mysql driver is also in the web-inf/lib dir

Comment: [WARN] /gwt_sales_reporting_tool/rpc/gwtservice
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named GWTSales
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
 at com.jeroennouws.sales.controller.BranchJpaController.<init>(BranchJpaController.java:29)
 at com.jeroennouws.sales.server.rpc.GWTServiceImpl.<init>(GWTServiceImpl.java:14)
this is part of the stacktrace

Comment: It is a common mistake, that's why I mentioned it. The other common mistake is having no database connectivity. If you 've checked that too, we run out of those :)

Comment: hehe made that mistake all to much to not check it ;) what do you exactly mean with having no DB connectivity?

Comment: Are you sure your DB server is up n' running, do you get a connection with mysql from, say, a terminal? Foolish I know, but it never hurts to ask :)

Comment: ah, yes mysql is up and running, in eclipse i can also ping my DB